# How to shift item position in UIKit

Tags: iphone, uiview, uikit, transform

Sorry guys, I hate asking dumb questions but I have seriously been searching for days online to no avail. Every method I've tried with `item.bounds` or the like has failed miserably. I'm just trying to move some elements, like a `UILabel` and a `UIButton` over a few pixels under a certain circumstance. Just a simple point to a tutorial that I missed would be so helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally frame is what you want. It is specified in terms of parent view coordinates. So if my view's frame is `CGRectMake(10.f,20.f,50.f,60.f)` it appears in the parent's coordinates at x=10 y=20 with width 50 and height 60.

```
UIView* someView ...

CGRect someViewFrame = someView.frame;
someView.frame.origin.y += 10;
someView.frame = someViewFrame;
```

moves the view down by 10 pixels.

If you just want to move the view in a superview, leave bounds alone.

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html) should be useful.